# Build KafkaOffsetMonitor tool manually

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to monitor kafka using KafkaOffsetMonitor tool. It is working fine as I used already built jar available at its github page. Now I want to make some changes in this tool but I dont know how to manually build it. I have downloaded the zip file from github page. Now how should I build it?

PS: Steps would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps which may help you: 
1. Checkout and get the source code into your local machine or you may have to unzip it if you have downloaded zip file.
2. Go to the folder which you have extracted or checked-out.
3. Run below command:

**mvn clean package -U -DskipTests**

Note: make sure you have installed maven in your machine.

Make the changes in the source if you want to modify the tool and build it using above steps.

Comment: can you tell me what type of project you have?? Is it Gradle?

Comment: If it is a Gradle project you can run "gradle build -X tests"

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm coming at this pretty late, but I ran into the same problem. Basically, you need a Java jdk, scala, and sbt installed first. You didn't post what os you're dealing with, so it would be hard for me to give you steps for that. I use Gentoo Linux and you can install it by running `emerge -av sbt`

Once sbt is installed, just clone [KafkaOffsetMonitor Github repository](https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor) change to the top level directory and run the following sbt command: `sbt assembly`

The jar you will be looking for will be in: `./target/scala-<scala_version>/KafkaOffsetMonitor-assembly-<kafkaoffsetmonitor_version>.jar`